# Google Maps API: getFeatureById for feature collection not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I try to change the style of a specific feature of a feature collection data overlay. This is a snippet of my json:

```html
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 1,
      "properties": {
        "name": "1 CBD - Bankenviertel",
        "color": "transparent",
        "isHovered": false,
        "isActive": false
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              8.67279430349,
              50.1143807311
            ],
            [
              8.67280054398,
              50.1143975981
            ]
        ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

and this is the relevant snippet from my map.js

```js
map.data.loadGeoJson('some.json');
console.log(map.data.getFeatureById(1));
```

And I am always getting "undefined" in the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `map.data.getFeatureById(1)` inside the callback function (so it doesn't execute before the GeoJson has loaded).

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data):

> **loadGeoJson**(url:string, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions, **callback?:function(Array<Data.Feature>)**)

> Return Value:  None

> Loads GeoJS

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q8vq796b/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: {
        lat: -28,
        lng: 137
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1teyu', {},
    function(features) {
      console.log(map.data.getFeatureById(1));
      console.log(map.data.getFeatureById(1).getProperty("letter"));
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```